Did a fire come down from Heaven to consume incense in the Tabernacle?
My understanding is that in the Beit HaMikdash a fire (perhaps in the form of a lion or other animal) would come down from Heaven and consume the sacrifices on the altar (1 Kings 18). I would like to know if there are any sources which discuss whether or not a similar event would take place with the incense altar in the Mishkan.

Vayikra 10: 1-2
